# How can I use a jOOQ custom code generator strategy with Gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, code-generation, jooq

This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10322155/how-to-use-a-custom-strategy-with-the-jooq-code-generator-and-maven), but we're using Gradle instead. Assume we're using jOOQ's code generation directly in our build script [as canonically described in the docs](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.7/manual/code-generation/codegen-gradle/).

There are two problems. First, we'll add a new `strategy` to the generator config, which should be straightforward:

```
// ...
generator() {
    // ...
    strategy() {
        name('com.example.MyCustomGeneratorStrategy')
    }
}
```

However, if we `println` the resultant XML configuration, the `name` element is mysteriously omitted (and silently too):

```
<generator>
    <!-- ... -->
    <strategy />
</generator>
```

Second, what mechanism can be used to pre-compile the generator strategy class (`com.example.MyCustomGeneratorStrategy`) and have it available in the classpath of the build script? One possible wrinkle here: the strategy code has a dependency on jOOQ's codegen module (and could have other dependencies too - for example ours depends on Apache Commons Lang).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first problem (`name` being silently omitted) seems to be a similar issue as described in the question [Groovy MarkupBuilder name conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11389034/236139). Following the recommendation of the answer there, we can fix problem #1 by doing:

```
// ...
generator() {
    // ...
    strategy() {
        delegate.invokeMethod('name', 'com.example.MyCustomGeneratorStrategy')
    }
}
```

(Of course, put a descriptive comment above that nonsense to deter any future monkeying...) With that in place, the XML configuration is actually correct:

```
<strategy>
  <name>com.example.MyCustomGeneratorStrategy</name>
</strategy>
```

The second problem (pre-compiling the strategy class and placing it in the build script's classpath) is [already solved by Gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_build_logic.html#sec:build_sources): use the special `buildSrc` project. That is, put a `buildSrc` directory in the project root. Set up `buildSrc/build.gradle` to include the jOOQ codegen dependency and any others you might need:

```
repositories() {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:+'
    compile 'org.jooq:jooq-codegen:+'
}
```

And then in `buildSrc/src/main/java`, you can place your generator strategy class. With that, code generation should Just Work (Gradle will pre-compile the stuff in `buildSrc` for you). If you messed something up with the generator class and it can't be found, jOOQ should throw a `ClassNotFoundException` anyway.

(Note: We're using the rest of the build script configuration as described in the [jOOQ docs](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.7/manual/code-generation/codegen-gradle/). The above may not be helpful if you stray from that.)

Comment: Do you have an idea whether something like buildSrc exists for Maven?