Classpath problems with Jooq custom code generator strategy
I am trying to run Jooq code generation with a custom code generator strategy. Using matcher rules worked but was too limited for my case. Code generation is called by Maven and its configuration is embedded in the POM, as is the source code for the custom strategy:
...
<build>
    <plugins>
        ...

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq-codegen-maven</artifactId>
            <version>3.19.9</version>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>

            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                    <version>42.7.3</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>

            <configuration>

                <jdbc>
                    <driver>org.postgresql.Driver</driver>
                    <url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/user_management</url>
                    <user>postgres</user>
                    <password>postgres</password>
                </jdbc>

                <generator>
                    <database>
                        <name>org.jooq.meta.postgres.PostgresDatabase</name>
                        <includes>.*</includes>
                        <schemata>
                            <schema>
                                <inputSchema>user_management</inputSchema>
                            </schema>
                        </schemata>
                    </database>

                    <generate/>

                    <strategy>
                        <name>name.martingeisse.user_management.jooq_config.MyDatabaseStrategy</name>
                        <java>
                            package name.martingeisse.user_management.jooq_config;

                            import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;
                            import org.jooq.*;
                            import org.jooq.Record; // Starting with Java 14, Record can not be imported on demand anymore
                            import org.jooq.impl.*;
                            import org.jooq.codegen.DefaultGeneratorStrategy;

                            public class MyDatabaseStrategy extends DefaultGeneratorStrategy {

                                @Override
                                public String getJavaIdentifier(Definition definition) {
                                    return definition.getOutputName();
                                }

                                @Override
                                public String getJavaSetterName(Definition definition, Mode mode) {
                                    return "set" + org.jooq.tools.StringUtils.toLC(definition.getOutputName());
                                }

                                @Override
                                public String getJavaGetterName(Definition definition, Mode mode) {
                                    return "get" + org.jooq.tools.StringUtils.toLC(definition.getOutputName());
                                }

                                @Override
                                public String getJavaMethodName(Definition definition, Mode mode) {
                                    return "call" + org.jooq.tools.StringUtils.toLC(definition.getOutputName());
                                }

                                @Override
                                public String getJavaClassName(Definition definition, Mode mode) {
                                    return definition.getOutputName();
                                }

                                @Override
                                public String getJavaMemberName(Definition definition, Mode mode) {
                                    return definition.getOutputName();
                                }

                            }
                        </java>


                    </strategy>

                    <target>
                        <packageName>name.martingeisse.user_management.jooq.user_management.jooq</packageName>
                        <directory>target/generated-sources/jooq</directory>
                    </target>
                    
                </generator>

            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
...

Errors:
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jooq:jooq-codegen-maven:3.19.9:generate (default) on project usermanagement-experiment-backend: Error running jOOQ code generation tool: Compilation error: /name/martingeisse/user_management/jooq_config/MyDatabaseStrategy.java:7: error: package org.jooq.codegen does not exist
[ERROR]                                 import org.jooq.codegen.DefaultGeneratorStrategy;
[ERROR]                                                        ^
[ERROR] /name/martingeisse/user_management/jooq_config/MyDatabaseStrategy.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]                                 public class MyDatabaseStrategy extends DefaultGeneratorStrategy {
[ERROR]                                                                         ^
[ERROR]   symbol: class DefaultGeneratorStrategy
[ERROR] /name/martingeisse/user_management/jooq_config/MyDatabaseStrategy.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]                                     public String getJavaIdentifier(Definition definition) {
[ERROR]                                                                     ^
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Definition
[ERROR]   location: class MyDatabaseStrategy
... (more of the same)

How can I make the codegen package available to my custom strategy?

Not sure why the transitive dependencies aren't available to your plugin execution, but you can always put them on the plugin or project classpath explicitly, i.e.:
<!-- .. -->
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
        <artifactId>jooq-meta</artifactId>
        <version>${jooq.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
        <artifactId>jooq-codegen</artifactId>
        <version>${jooq.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


Thank you for your quick reply. This did not seem to change anything. Note that the problem seems to be the classpath used by the compiler to resolve referenced classes, not the run-time classpath. Unfortunately, I wasn't successful running code in a static{} block to debug the run-time classpath, possibly because Java doesn't run that block until needed.

@MartinGeisse: The compiler in question is Java's in-memory compiler, which is used by jOOQ behind the scenes to compile your inline <java> code, so it does need the libraries on the classpath. You can check the classpath with a debugger by setting a breakpoint in GenerationTool.compile()

I found that the compiler can resolve the classses when I add them to the dependencies of the project itself (top-level "dependencies" element in the POM) instead of the dependencies of the jooq-codegen-maven plugin. Maybe this helps to track down the issue. WRT to running a debugger: I can try, but I don't have any experience running a debugger outside IntelliJ, and the latter won't work correctly unless it has access to the exact same source code being debugged (without the source code, it won't even show you the byte code that gets executed).

@MartinGeisse: OK, that's interesting, thanks for the follow-up. It shouldn't matter where you add the dependencies (in Maven, ordinarily, you must add such dependencies to the plugin, but jOOQ's plugin did some tricks to override this default. Possibly, there's a bug hidden here, which prevents plugin dependencies to be added to the compiler classpath. Will look into this soon)

Thanks a lot. For now I'm fine with adding it to the main dependency. In case it helps, my Maven version is 3.9.6 (bc0240f3c744dd6b6ec2920b3cd08dcc295161ae), Java version 17.0.8.1.fx-librca (BellSoft).

I followed this approach https://stackoverflow.com/a/10946266/4510444 and it worked, I moved the custom generator to a different module and added it as a dependency - works in both plugin or project classpath. I would like to be able to solve it in the same module, but I couldn't. So in the end I opted for this.

@LukasEder I'm not sure if this documented in the jooq guides, but it might be good to mention this approach (using a different module) as I saw a lot of similar issues in both maven and gradle codegen.

@Aaron: It's mentioned in multiple locations, and it's quite logical IMO. But indeed, it's not mentioned in the relevant section for generator strategies.
